# How to read GET and POST data in C?

Tags: c, interface, cgi

I'm running a web server. I'm using CGI, specifically C: I compile `.c` files into `.out` files, and then rename them to `.cgi`. I'm having quite some trouble reading GET and POST data: after dumping argv I noticed that GET data appears on either `argv[25]` or `argv[26]`, quite randomly - I didn't check POST data.
So the question is, how can a C program read GET or POST data through CGI?

Answer (score 1):

Use getenv

[How to retrieve form "POST" data via cgi-bin program written in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451913/how-to-retrieve-form-post-data-via-cgi-bin-program-written-in-c)

http://www.codingunit.com/c-reference-stdlib-h-function-getenv