# How to call a function written in C with axios?

Tags: javascript, jquery, c, ajax, axios

I’ve used a microcontroller to develop the embedded web server and I’m not sure if I can download an Apache or any other server into my controller.

However, I’ve successfully implemented an HTTP interface and have been hosting web pages and handling & parsing the POST request data/payload at the embedded web server side.

The issue is coming when the web page contains any form type data to be submitted.

I receive the value(s) entered by the user on the web page but I'm not able to display the data properly on the web page sent by the embedded server.

That’s where there’s a major issue in linking C (freeRTOS) code (server side) and JS (client side).

How can a JS web client pull data from embedded web server (in freeRTOS) given that I have a successful HTTP connection established with the web page and I'm also able to host pages as mentioned above?

Currently I'm using axios but unable to figure out how to call a C function in the URL? As it's not possible to code in C without a function.

```
axios({
method: 'post',
url: 'getStatus.c',
data: sampleData,
headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
})
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
})
```

Comment: Axios is an HTTP client. Are you running a server that will call the function?

Comment: It's an embedded web server in freeRTOS

Answer (score 2):

### You cannot directly call a function in uncompiled C source file.

axios is a client side ( JS lib ) technology. Any server side program that you want to interact with axios must implement some sort of HTTP interface.

### If you must use C to achieve something like that:

1. **Implement a CGI interface in C**

CGI program can as simple as something like this ( Handling POST request is bit more difficult ):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n");
  printf("<html>\n");
  printf("<body>\n");
  printf("<h1>Hello there!</h1>\n");
  printf("</body>\n");
  printf("</html>\n");
  return 0;
}
```

**You can access POST request data the following way:**

```
len_ = getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH");
len = strtol(len_, NULL, 10);
postdata = malloc(len + 1);
if (!postdata) { /* handle error or */ exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
fgets(postdata, len + 1, stdin);
/* work with postdata */
free(postdata);
```

[How to retrieve form "POST" data via cgi-bin program written in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451913/how-to-retrieve-form-post-data-via-cgi-bin-program-written-in-c)

More on CGI C programs: http://jkorpela.fi/forms/cgic.html

Consider using libcgi http://libcgi.sourceforge.net for CGI C programs.

2. **Compile the CGI program.**
3. **Use Apache2 or Nginx to serve the CGI "script" in this case the compiled binary.**

---

### If using C is not a priority:

I would recommend to use a high level language which is more suitable for web development. Python / PHP / C# / Java / etc..

Comment: As much as I have read about CGI, online and also from the links you have provided I cannot find the relevance/usage of an Apache or Nginx server in the C code. Also, I have updated the question to elaborate the issue.

Comment: Well, what i have written above is mainly applicable to regular servers running linux/Windows.  However calling the function/file directly is not common, i have only seen vanilla PHP ( w/o url routing ) do something similar. Keep in mind that PHP is an interpreted language C is not. Most frameworks/languages require you to implement a wrapper function that handles the HTTP routing and passes down the args to the function. Please provide the getStatus.c source code and name the the freertos http lib used